# convert float to integer

Tags: math, image-processing, vhdl, dct

how to scale and by which factor to scale dctmtx coefficients from float to get following integer values:

float dctmtx:

```
( (0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536    0.3536),
    (0.4904    0.4157    0.2778    0.0975   -0.0975   -0.2778   -0.4157   -0.4904),
    (0.4619    0.1913   -0.1913   -0.4619   -0.4619   -0.1913    0.1913    0.4619),
    (0.4157   -0.0975   -0.4904   -0.2778    0.2778    0.4904    0.0975   -0.4157),
    (0.3536   -0.3536   -0.3536    0.3536    0.3536   -0.3536   -0.3536    0.3536),
    (0.2778   -0.4904    0.0975    0.4157   -0.4157   -0.0975    0.4904   -0.2778),
    (0.1913   -0.4619    0.4619   -0.1913   -0.1913    0.4619   -0.4619    0.1913),
    (0.0975   -0.2778    0.4157   -0.4904    0.4904   -0.4157    0.2778   -0.0975)
)
```

integer dctmtx:

```
(( 125,   122,   115,    103,    88,     69,     47,      24  ),
        ( 125,   103,    47,    -24,   -88,   -122,   -115,     -69  ),
        ( 125,    69,   -47,   -122,   -88,     24,    115,     103  ),
        ( 125,    24,  -115,    -69,    88,    103,    -47,    -122  ),
        ( 125,   -24,  -115,     69,    88,   -103,    -47,     122  ),
        ( 125,   -69,   -47,    122,   -88,    -24,    115,    -103  ),
        ( 125,  -103,    47,     24,   -88,    122,   -115,      69  ),
        ( 125,  -122,   115,   -103,    88,    -69,     47,     -24  )
    );
```

Comment: This seems impossible to answer, since both -0.0975 and -0.4619 get mapped to -88. Please give more information on the provenance and connection of both arrays.

Comment: However, if you were to transpose the second matrix, and rescale the rows independently, then at least that gives a match. But still, 0.3536 gets once mapped tp 125 and in the fifth row to 88.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read up on the discrete cosine transform, you will find that the basic coefficient is

```
cos(pi*i*(2*j+1)/16),  i,j=0..7
```

Then the first table consists of these values scaled by 0.5, except for the first row/column, which is scaled by 0.25*sqrt(2)=1/sqrt(8). Which is the correct way to obtain an orthogonal matrix. The square sum of the first column is 8, of the others 4.

The second table is the rounded results when multiplying the cosine values with 125, uniformly. Here one has to take care to properly rescale the vector when using the transpose matrix to compute the inverse transform.

---

First table reproduced, except for the first column:

```
> [[ Cos(pi*i*(2*j+1)/16)/2 : i in [0..7] ]: j in [0..7] ];        
[
    [ 0.5, 0.49039264, 0.46193977, 0.41573481, 0.35355339, 0.27778512, 0.19134172, 0.09754516 ],
    [ 0.5, 0.41573481, 0.19134172, -0.09754516, -0.35355339, -0.49039264, -0.46193977, -0.27778512 ],
    [ 0.5, 0.27778512, -0.19134172, -0.49039264, -0.35355339, 0.09754516, 0.46193977, 0.41573481 ],
    [ 0.5, 0.09754516, -0.46193977, -0.27778512, 0.35355339, 0.41573481, -0.19134172, -0.49039264 ],
    [ 0.5, -0.09754516, -0.46193977, 0.27778512, 0.35355339, -0.41573481, -0.19134172, 0.49039264 ],
    [ 0.5, -0.27778512, -0.19134172, 0.49039264, -0.35355339, -0.09754516, 0.46193977, -0.41573481 ],
    [ 0.5, -0.41573481, 0.19134172, 0.09754516, -0.35355339, 0.49039264, -0.46193977, 0.27778512 ],
    [ 0.5, -0.49039264, 0.46193977, -0.41573481, 0.35355339, -0.27778512, 0.19134172, -0.09754516 ]
]
```

---

Second table, before integer rounding

```
> [[ Cos( pi*i*(2*j+1)/16 ) *125 : i in [0..7] ]: j in [0..7] ];       
[
    [ 125, 122.5982, 115.4849, 103.9337, 88.3883, 69.4463, 47.8354, 24.3863 ],
    [ 125, 103.9337, 47.8354, -24.3863, -88.3883, -122.5982, -115.4849, -69.4463 ],
    [ 125, 69.4463, -47.8354, -122.5982, -88.3883, 24.3863, 115.4849, 103.9337 ],
    [ 125, 24.3863, -115.4849, -69.4463, 88.3883, 103.9337, -47.8354, -122.5982 ],
    [ 125, -24.3863, -115.4849, 69.4463, 88.3883, -103.9337, -47.8354, 122.5982 ],
    [ 125, -69.4463, -47.8354, 122.5982, -88.3883, -24.3863, 115.4849, -103.9337 ],
    [ 125, -103.9337, 47.8354, 24.3863, -88.3883, 122.5982, -115.4849, 69.4463 ],
    [ 125, -122.5982, 115.4849, -103.9337, 88.3883, -69.4463, 47.8354, -24.3863 ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides one of the two matrices being rotated the two don't appear to have a direct linear relationship:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float dctmtx[8][8] = 
  { 0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,
    0.4904,   0.4157,   0.2778,   0.0975,  -0.0975,  -0.2778,  -0.4157,  -0.4904,
    0.4619,   0.1913,  -0.1913,  -0.4619,  -0.4619,  -0.1913,   0.1913,   0.4619,
    0.4157,  -0.0975,  -0.4904,  -0.2778,   0.2778,   0.4904,   0.0975,  -0.4157,
    0.3536,  -0.3536,  -0.3536,   0.3536,   0.3536,  -0.3536,  -0.3536,   0.3536,
    0.2778,  -0.4904,   0.0975,   0.4157,  -0.4157,  -0.0975,   0.4904,  -0.2778,
    0.1913,  -0.4619,   0.4619,  -0.1913,  -0.1913,   0.4619,  -0.4619,   0.1913,
    0.0975,  -0.2778,   0.4157,  -0.4904,   0.4904,  -0.4157,   0.2778,  -0.0975
  };

    int j,k, i;
    float m;
    for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            if ( k == 0) 
                m = (dctmtx[k][j] * 354) ;
            else 
                m = (dctmtx[k][j] * 248) ;
            i = lroundf(m);
            printf("%4d ",i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

The first coefficient in each row appears to be to a different accuracy than the remaining:

```
%% convftoi
 125  122  115  103   88   69   47   24
 125  103   47  -24  -88 -122 -115  -69
 125   69  -47 -122  -88   24  115  103
 125   24 -115  -69   88  103  -47 -122
 125  -24 -115   69   88 -103  -47  122
 125  -69  -47  122  -88  -24  115 -103
 125 -103   47   24  -88  122 -115   69
 125 -122  115 -103   88  -69   47  -24
```

After a little finessing to find scaling factors that did give a match.

**addendum**

After LutzL's answer I derived the float coefficient matrix algorithmically:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265359

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  float calcmtx[8][8];

    int j,k, i;
    float m;
    printf("float coefficients calculated\n");
    for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            if ( j == 0) 
                m = cos(PI*j*(2*k+1)/16)/(sqrt(2)*2) ;
            else 
                m = cos(PI*j*(2*k+1)/16)/2 ;
            calcmtx[k][j] = floorf(m*10000 + 0.5)/10000;
        }
    }

    for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            printf("% 2.4f ", calcmtx[k][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n") ;

    printf("integer coefficients derived\n");
    for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            if (k == 0)
                m = sqrt(2);
            else
                m = 1;
            i = (int) (calcmtx[j][k] * 250 * m);
            printf("%4d ", i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n") ;

    printf("approximated integer coefficients\n");
    for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        for ( k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            if ( k == 0) 
                m = calcmtx[j][k] * 354 ;
            else 
                m = calcmtx[j][k] * 248 ;
            i = lroundf(m);
            printf("%4d ", i);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

And we see that the integer matrix first coefficient is multiplied by the square root of two:

```
%% gencoeffi
float coefficients calculated
 0.3536  0.3536  0.3536  0.3536  0.3536  0.3536  0.3536  0.3536
 0.4904  0.4157  0.2778  0.0975 -0.0975 -0.2778 -0.4157 -0.4904
 0.4619  0.1913 -0.1913 -0.4619 -0.4619 -0.1913  0.1913  0.4619
 0.4157 -0.0975 -0.4904 -0.2778  0.2778  0.4904  0.0975 -0.4157
 0.3536 -0.3536 -0.3536  0.3536  0.3536 -0.3536 -0.3536  0.3536
 0.2778 -0.4904  0.0975  0.4157 -0.4157 -0.0975  0.4904 -0.2778
 0.1913 -0.4619  0.4619 -0.1913 -0.1913  0.4619 -0.4619  0.1913
 0.0975 -0.2778  0.4157 -0.4904  0.4904 -0.4157  0.2778 -0.0975

integer coefficients derived
 125  122  115  103   88   69   47   24
 125  103   47  -24  -88 -122 -115  -69
 125   69  -47 -122  -88   24  115  103
 125   24 -115  -69   88  103  -47 -122
 125  -24 -115   69   88 -103  -47  122
 125  -69  -47  122  -88  -24  115 -103
 125 -103   47   24  -88  122 -115   69
 125 -122  115 -103   88  -69   47  -24

approximated integer coefficients
 125  122  115  103   88   69   47   24
 125  103   47  -24  -88 -122 -115  -69
 125   69  -47 -122  -88   24  115  103
 125   24 -115  -69   88  103  -47 -122
 125  -24 -115   69   88 -103  -47  122
 125  -69  -47  122  -88  -24  115 -103
 125 -103   47   24  -88  122 -115   69
 125 -122  115 -103   88  -69   47  -24
```

Which matches the approximation when the float accuracy is limited.